# Basic Symmetric Group Question

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Let $$σ =
\begin{pmatrix}1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\
3 &4 &2 &8 &5 &7 &6 &10 &1& 9 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Find $σ^{2345}$ and express it as $σ^k$, with $k$ minimal.

Comment: Hint : decompose $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: I tried to decompose it as a product of disjoint cycles but am then confused as to where to go from there.

Comment: So what is the result as a disjoint product of cycles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By straightforward calculation, we see that 
\begin{align*}
1&\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 4\rightarrow
8\rightarrow 10\rightarrow 9\rightarrow1&&(7\mbox{-cycle)}\\
5&\rightarrow 5&&(1\mbox{-cycle)}\\
6&\rightarrow 7\rightarrow 6&&(2\mbox{-cycle)}
\end{align*}
and thus $\sigma^{14}=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\end{pmatrix}=\iota$ (identity symbol). Hence we conclude that
$$\sigma^{2345}=\sigma^7\circ(\sigma^{14})^{167}
=\sigma^7\circ\iota^{167}
=\sigma^7
=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
1&2&3&4&5&7&6&8&9&10\end{pmatrix}$$
and $k=7$.